# Accessing SQLite3 directly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am stating out learning Ruby on Rails. For that I am using "Agile Web Development with Rails 4th edition book" which basically walks you through the creation of a sample project.

Even though I am getting the basics down from it I have failed to understand what I believe is a fundamental concept. Where exactly is the relational database and how can I access it directly?

If I was using PHP/MySQL I would go to phpmyadmin and could query the data directly.

How can achieve this with SQLite3?

I am using Linux (Ubuntu) and installed ror and sqlite with gem.

Thanks.

Comment: This question covers alternatives to phpmyadmin for sqlite3

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332250/windows-gui-tool-for-sqlite3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your Rails root you can access the database command line directly with:

```
$ sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.5
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 4):

The SQLite3 database is stored in a file, usually located in the db/ folder. If you use Firefox, I recommend the [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) addon.

You can use other databases if you want to, see [3.3 Configuring a Database](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database) in the getting started guide for rails.